# Debugging default settings

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to activate hot reloading and remote debugging on default. It's tedious do to it all the time when I'm starting developing. Also on the device shaking takes too much time. It  would be better that it can be triggered via terminal.

Is this possible?

Comment: you talk about yellow box warning?

Comment: No. The debugger + hot reloading.